# Wix - how to uninstall services on MSI Uninstall

Tags: wix

I hope you guys are having a good and healthy day specially nowadays! I just need some help in Wix installer. I have a .msi installer created using WIX. The installer also install some windows services. After installing the .msi, services are installed and running properly after. But in uninstall/removed of the .msi, services are not being deleted. Below is the code i'm using, please correct me if there's anything wrong in my code:

```
<Directory Id="serviceencrypt" Name="service-encryption">
  <Component Id="MyAppEncryption">
    <File
    Id="MyAppEncryptionEXE"
    Name="MyApp.Encryption.exe"
    DiskId="1"
    Source="$(var.MyAppInstallerFiles)\application\service-encryption\MyApp.Encryption.exe"
    Vital="yes"
    KeyPath="yes" />
    <ServiceInstall Id="MyAppEncryptionInstall" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes"
            Name="MyAppEncryption" DisplayName="MyApp Encryption"
            Description="MyApp Encryption" Start="auto"
            ErrorControl="normal"
            Arguments=" action:run" Interactive="no"  Account="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService">
    </ServiceInstall>
    <ServiceControl Id="MyAppEncryptionStartService" Stop="both" Start="install" Remove="uninstall"
        Name="MyAppEncryption" Wait="yes" />
  </Component>
</Directory>
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I would try on a **clean virtual** before trying anything else.

Comment: what do you mean here sir? I don't get it sorry. Should I clean my VM? Reset the VM?

Comment: Some machines can get "contaminated" by the installation of interim- or test-versions of your setup. This can cause problems not seen on "clean systems". So yes: please make sure to test on a clean virtual machine to see if you can reproduce the problem.